# ManyToManyField in django

Tags: django, django-models

I have the following model:

```
class Position(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    positions = models.ManyToManyField(Position)
```

How would I enter the following two statements correctly?

```
-- UserpProfile.objects.create(location = 'usa', positions = 'artist')
-- UserProfile.objects.create(location = 'usa', positions = 'artist', 'programmer', and 'teacher')
```

Note: I do not want to provide values for the user to choose from. I only want them to be able to enter multiple positions, and then to store those multiple positions in the table.

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I'm not sure if list assignment works in a constructor, but you can assign it this way:

```
 profile = UserProfile(location='usa')
 profile.positions = ['artist', 'programmer', 'teacher']
```